# Unsupported 64 bit video drivers for windows

Tags: windows, windows-vista, drivers, 64-bit, graphics-card

I've heard that generally one can find vista 64 bit drivers for video cards that don't have drivers from the manufacturers, but I haven't been able to find them myself.

Does anyone know where a good source for these drivers would be?

Comment: mind telling us make and model of the grahics card? :)

Comment: Usually you should find 64-bit drivers if there are 32-bit drivers as well. All devices bearing a Vista-capable logo have to have 32-bit *and* 64-bit drivers, as mandated by Microsoft. If you can't find them mayhaps your video card is old enough to not even have Vista drivers at all.

Comment: It's an ATI model is 'VGA POWERCOLOR 24PRO256M PCI RT' for what it's worth,  my co-worker bought it to get a third monitor and the Vista 64 drivers just don't seem to work (not a big surprise). 
I think I may have found a driver for this particular thing. I'm more interested in finding a repo of unsupported windows drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I know what you are talking about -

Typically, Nvidia and ATI laptop graphic drivers are best from the manufacturers site.

If you have a laptop, it used to be the fact that you can only get updated drivers (for Nvidia, not sure on ATI) from the manufacturers.

Before Nvidia released laptop drivers directly, the place to get them was usually [Laptop Video 2 Go](http://www.laptopvideo2go.com/).

Comment: Yeah, I'm just talking about hacked drivers for unsupported platforms.

Comment: Well, the site I lined to has a very good guide and INF file modifier

Answer (score 0):

You can either source video card drivers from the card manufacturer (e.g. PNY making a graphics card with nVidia chipsets) or you can go right to the chipset manufacturer (e.g. nVidia) and download the latest and greatest driver package (or the archived version that works with your machine).  For reference designs I've found in the past that I had more success just shooting over to the chipset manufacturer website.

Answer (score -1):

The 'VGA POWERCOLOR 24PRO256M PCI RT' graphic card is based on an ATI Radeon HD 2400PRO chipset with 256MB RAM.

You can use [the ATI Windows drivers](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) for this card.

Comment: Those drivers are a little too supported